# Locale for Romanian

Tags: android

After googling a while I find Android 2.3 version does support it.. but I didn't find the minimum version it support.. If Android 2.2 version does not support Romanian then what is the alternative.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: You can refer the URLs below, [http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) [http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615587/localization-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615587/localization-android)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the similar problem that got solved:

[What is the list of supported languages/locales on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973023/what-is-the-list-of-supported-languages-locales-on-android)

According to this answer, Romanian Locale is get supported since v2.3

And you can always use

`public Locale (String language, String country)`

to construct a Locale.

As [@talhakosen mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13510462/763459), you probably should take a look at the API documentation.