# Locale.SPANISH where is it?

Tags: android, locale

I try to change the language of my application to Spanish, but I cannot find it.

```
Configuration c = new Configuration(getResources().getConfiguration());
c.locale = Locale.SPANISH; // does not exists
```

But this works:

```
c.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
```

Could somebody help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Did you try `Locale spanish = new Locale("es", "ES");`

(see [Localization Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615587/localization-android))

Comment: yes and eclipse say me:
      spanish cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: fixed
Locale spanish = new Locale("es", "ES");
c.locale = spanish;


this works THAnks!!

Comment: You may consider marking this as useful or answered - hope you got it all working

Comment: i can´t click in useful :(

Comment: Or just `new Locale("es")`