# Multilanguage app from spinner android

Tags: android

I am doing multilanguage Android app. I have a spinner to select from the app the different languages to the app and save the selected language in shared preferences. I am novice and I have seen that there isn´t Locale.SPANISH, I am doing well?, here is my code:

```
 Configuration config = new Configuration();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
            Locale spanish = new Locale("es", "ES");
            savePreferences("idioma", spanish.toString());
             break;
            case 1:
             config.locale = Locale.FRENCH;
             savePreferences("idioma", config.locale.toString());
             break;
            case 2:
                 config.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
                 savePreferences("idioma", config.locale.toString());
            break;
            default:

             break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate your translates with help of `strings.xml`, and there will be no need to handle locale by your own. Look on this [article at Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html).

And this is how you can get Spanish locale:

```
Locale spanish = new Locale("es", "ES");
```

(see [Localization Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615587/localization-android))

Comment: yes, but to do this the device it has to be in the language selected. If I have my device in spanish and I want to change the app´s language to english?

Answer (score 0):

To force the locale of your app you can use this in `onCreate` or when you press a button or whereever you need to change the lenguage of your app:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("es", "ES");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Hope it helps!

**EDIT:**

You will also need to have a `strings.xml` for each locale stored in the proper folder (ex: values-es, values-en, values-fr, etc...)